# Android optimize Glide and storage image

Tags: android, image, optimization, storage, android-glide

I'm using Glide to download images come from web service result. After that I store my images in the external storage and next time if the files exist I'll not download the images I'll just search the images in the device and I display them into the Gridview. But the `new File()` make my Gridview slow when I'm scrolling and I have a warning for each images and each scroll :

`Failed to ensure directory: /storage/sdcard1/Android/data/com.my.package/files/Pictures`

How can I optimize the `new file()` line or store my images in another directory ? And remove this warning.

***Note: When I don't save the images in the device my Gridview is really smooth but I have to save them :/.***

**Adapter getView()**

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view;
    final ImageView imageView;
    final TextView legend;

    // Soft display
    if(convertView == null){
        view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.thumbnail_gallery, parent, false);
    }else{
        view = convertView;
    }

    // Get layout item (Image and Legend)
    imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_thumbnail);
    legend = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_thumb);

    // Do not display old images
    imageView.setImageDrawable(null);

    // Get the file path
    //**************************************************\\
    //******** This line make my gridview laggy *********\\
    //****************************************************\\
    final File file = new File(mContext.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), mPInfoList.get(position).getFilename());

    // Get the download path image
    String pic = Globals.SERVER_NAME+Globals
                        .ACCOUNT_SERVER_PATH+mPInfoList
                        .get(position).getFolderPath()+"/"+
                        VgzTools.addSuffix(mPInfoList.get(position).getFilename(), "-thumb");

    // Check file exist
    if(!file.exists()){

        // Create a Simple Target for Glide
        SimpleTarget<Bitmap> simpleTarget = new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            public void onResourceReady(final Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation glideAnimation) {
                // Thread to save the image
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            // Image saving
                            FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
                            resource.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fileOutput);
                            fileOutput.close();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }).start();

                imageView.setImageBitmap(resource);
                // Set the legend
                if (mPInfoList.get(position).getFilename() != null) {
                    legend.setText(mPInfoList.get(position).getLegend());
                }
            }
        };

        // File doesn't exist Save image
        Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(pic)
                .asBitmap()
                .into(simpleTarget);
    }else{
        // File exist then display it
        Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(file)
                .into(imageView);
    }

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Your purpose of storing images in device is only to display them next time. Right? Since you are using Glide, this functionality is already done in Glide.

Comment: Glide save the images in the cache, not in the device.

Comment: Right. Purpose is to avoid re-downloading. You too need that. right?

Comment: Yes I want to do that

Comment: So Glide save automatically all images ?

Comment: Yes. https://futurestud.io/blog/glide-getting-started

Comment: Wow nice and it will never delete the image in the cache ? And it is possible to get the images info ?

Comment: No. Only images are cached and they retain until cache gets cleared.

Comment: But now it's impossible to get the filename or the image to display it in another activity.

Comment: Ok I understand. I can get them if I call the same URL and it works in offline too it's very nice. Thanks for you help.